# Disable Command+S shortcut for saving files in MacVim

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macvim

Is there any way to disable MacVim's <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> shortcut for saving files? I'm sure there's a way to do it, since the same is possible with the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> shortcut by doing this:

```
if has("gui_macvim")
    macmenu &File.New\ Tab key=<nop>
endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right on it. Using the same logic, following the menu items.

```
if has("gui_macvim")
    macmenu &File.Save key=<nop>
endif
```

Comment: So close! This works if the file hasn't already been saved, but if the file has already been given a filename pressing Command+S does what it should.

Comment: I figured out the rest by myself. I just did `map <D-s> <ESC>` so it doesn't do anything at all. Thanks a ton!